# Can you rename an ONNX model with Java

Tags: java, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, onnx

We are getting different versions of the models from the client but they are all named the same and the client cannot change the name because of the way they have training set up.
We need to upload the models to Cumulocity Zementis but it will not accept two models with the same name.

**Question is**, is it possible to change the name of the model with Java ?

We have tried microsofts onnxruntime library, we can get OnnxModelMetaData but this object is immutable. We didn't find any methods that would allow us to change the models name and export the modified model.

All wee need to do is append a suffix with version to the models name.

Even a hint of how to deal with this problem would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help somebody.
After extensive search I have not found a Java solution to the problem.
But using python renaming the model is rather trivial.
Using onnx library we simply load the model and the name will be at

```
model.graph.name
```

We have created a simple service with one endpoint using flask that takes a model as byte[], loads it, renames it and returns the byte[] representation of the model.

If you find by any chance a Java way of doing this, please let me know :)